# Why can a port can be accessible from outside although it is not in firewall open ports on centos 7?

Tags: centos, networking, firewalld

I have a remote vps working with centos 7, related firewalld info is as below, firewalld is running actively.

```
[root@doer mydir]# firewall-cmd --get-zone-of-interface=eth0
no zone
[root@ doer mydir]# firewall-cmd --list-ports
You're performing an operation over default zone ('public'),
but your connections/interfaces are in zone 'home' (see --get-active-zones)
You most likely need to use --zone=home option.

3306/tcp
```

I run a docker with a springboot program listening on port 8080, which is mapped to 9182 of the host machine, 9182 is not in the opening ports list, but I can still access the web server through http://HOST_MACHINE_IP:9182, what is wrong?

Comment: Is 9182 the port for the container or the mapped port on the host? Is `IP`  the external host IP?

Comment: @xenoid updated

Comment: Post the result of `iptables -S`, probably firewalld have a not secure configuration